# Quarkus Camel build failing on kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a project using quarkus, camel which builds fine locally however when i try to build it on my CI environment (either through my jenkins environment or on bitbucket) I get a weird failure. I can't really track the source however and am quite stumped as to what can be causing this.  My kubernetes storage does not have any readonly flags enabled.
This fails only in kubernetes not even inside just a docker container started locally

```
[INFO] Building jar: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Build Jobs/Build Gateway Service Starter/target/gateway-service-starter-1.5.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.0.CR1:build (default) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] No Git Properties File Url Defined. Attempting with default: git.properties
[ERROR] Unable to load default git properties file git.properties
[INFO] [io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor] Quarkus augmentation completed in 10087ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.0.CR1:generate-code (default) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 54 source files to /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Build Jobs/Build Gateway Service Starter/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.0.CR1:generate-code-tests (default) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files to /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Build Jobs/Build Gateway Service Starter/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M6:test (default-test) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] Building jar: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/Build Jobs/Build Gateway Service Starter/target/gateway-service-starter-1.5.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.0.CR1:build (default) @ gateway-service-starter ---
[INFO] No Git Properties File Url Defined. Attempting with default: git.properties
[ERROR] Unable to load default git properties file git.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  02:14 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-30T13:34:00Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.9.0.CR1:build (default) on project gateway-service-starter: Failed to build quarkus application: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.CamelNativeImageProcessor#camelRuntimeCatalog threw an exception: java.nio.file.ClosedFileSystemException
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.ensureOpen(ZipFileSystem.java:1619)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getFileAttributes(ZipFileSystem.java:531)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:767)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:777)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:276)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory(Files.java:2322)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.util.CamelSupport.services(CamelSupport.java:71)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.CamelNativeImageProcessor.camelRuntimeCatalog(CamelNativeImageProcessor.java:170)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR]     [error]: Build step org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.CamelProcessor#camelServices threw an exception: java.nio.file.ClosedFileSystemException
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.ensureOpen(ZipFileSystem.java:1619)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystem.getFileAttributes(ZipFileSystem.java:531)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:767)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.readAttributes(ZipPath.java:777)
[ERROR]     at jdk.zipfs/jdk.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:276)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1851)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.isDirectory(Files.java:2322)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.util.CamelSupport.services(CamelSupport.java:71)
[ERROR]     at org.apache.camel.quarkus.core.deployment.CamelProcessor.camelServices(CamelProcessor.java:213)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
[ERROR]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:925)
[ERROR]     at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
[ERROR]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ERROR]     at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:501)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: I have exactely the same issue. Sometimes it works and sometimes not. But mostly it doesn't build in Openshift and ends up with the same exception you are facing. Did you find a solution?

Comment: We changed our infrastructure a bit, but weirdly enough the fix for this was to use mvn clean install instead of mvn clean verify package (I know. Doesn't make sense)

Comment: I did the same, without the package, it worked. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdly, the solution for us was to use `mvn clean install` rather than `mvn clean verify package`

Theoretically, shouldn't make the difference but it did.